# Creating a simple Dice object, without static 'sides' property available in the interface

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

Hello all in the community...
I just want to create an simple Dice object that allows the the user to chose a 'custom', or 'default' value for the number of 'sides' the dice will have at instantiating time. At the same time, the 'sides' isn't a static property of the object. And, the only interface available being Dice.roll.
Do you think this is a fair solution?

```
function Dice(num){
var sides = (num) ? num : 6;
this.roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides + 1); // The interface
}
var defaultdice = new Dice();    //  Default Dice, 6 sides
var dice4 = new Dice(4);        //  4 sides Dice
var dice2 = new Dice(2);       //  2 sides Dice 

console.log(defaultdice.roll,' ',dice4.roll,' ',dice2.roll);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you think this is a fair solution?

Looks fair to me! What makes you believe this is "unfair"?

---

If you're going to need to roll the same Dice instance multiple times, I'd suggest turning the `roll` property into a function; as follows,

```js
function Dice(num) {
  var sides = (num) ? num : 6;
  this.roll = function() {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * sides + 1);
  }
}
var defaultdice = new Dice(); //  Default Dice, 6 sides
var dice4 = new Dice(4); //  4 sides Dice
var dice2 = new Dice(2); //  2 sides Dice

console.log(defaultdice.roll(), ' ', dice4.roll(), ' ', dice2.roll());

// Sides is a private class member
// Trying to access it from the instance will return undefined
console.log(dice4.sides);
```

Comment: Hello Trent, I really appreciate your prompt answer, but that pattern you wrote, would make this.sides a static property of the Dice object? Like, the user could retrieve the side property by console.log(Dice.sides); ?

Comment: @LuvMyDog See my updated answer. Ordinary vars and parameters of the constructor become the private members.

Comment: indeed, now I get it...what a beauty. I up voted, but it doesn't show because I'm not qualified :-)  Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help. If you felt my answer has fulfilled this question, please mark it as accepted.